# How to put an r script into a package

Tags: r, package

I'm writing my first R package and have made a successful build with documentation using roxygen2 and added data sets.

However, I would also like ship an example script with how I use the functions in the r package. But I don't know where to put it.

Let's say I have created `MyPackage`. I have put my function scripts in the `/R` folder. Let's say I have:

```
foo1.R
foo2.R
foo3.R
```

Somewhere I'd also like to put a script with my workflow. Let's say I have a file, `MyWorkflow.R`:

```
library(MyPackage)
load(file='inData.R') # Loads indata variables A, B and C
X=foo1(A)
Y=foo2(X,B)
Z=foo3(Y,C)
```

Can I do this? If so, where do I put it? Is it an OK procedure - or generally frowned upon?

Any help or thoughts are appreciated.
Thanks.
Carl

**Edit:**

I looked at the link on `demo/` and `exec/`, but didn't understand the `exec/` folder thing. Grateful if you could clarify/exemplify/point to good uses of...

If I understand correctly, I'm not looking for an `example` or `demo/`, since the script won't necessarily be executable without tweaking by the user (e.g. to provide input data or paths). I "just" want to add an example script showing how I work with these functions.

I realise I should probably dive into the world of `vignettes`, but have difficulty in finding the time/oomph/energy to do so.

I also saw that there's the `inst/` folder. Could you shed some light on the different uses of these options or hint at good examples of where they've been used (I often find examples more informative than reading an explanatory text that's above my level - I often get the feeling of being like a dog looking at a ceiling fan ;)

Will add info to the GitHub README. Thx for good suggestion!

Comment: Do you mean an interactive example, as executed with `demo()` (see [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/demo.html))? If not, you may just be better off creating an additional vignette which walks through the content of `MyWorkflow.R`. It is common for package authors to include such vignettes which serve as a tutorial, etc... for working with their package.

Answer (score 3):

Created `inst/Workflow_Example/workflow.R`. Upon build & reload, a `Workflow_Example` folder was created in the library with `workflow.R` script in it.

In combination with an explanatory remark in the README, this looks like what I was after. Problem solved or am I not seeing something obvious? Am I e.g. violating conventions/conduct/good practice?

Comment: `check()` your pacakge. If `check()` doesn't complain about it then you're probably all right.

Comment: `R CMD check succeeded` - So, that would indicate I'm good :)

Answer (score 2):

You could either put it in `demo/` or `exec/` depending on the format of the script. See [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/misc.html) for more details. I would mention the workflow and where it lives in the README regardless, and if you host your code on Github, you could create a `wiki` to describe the workflow and place the script there. This would be similar to what nrussell has mentioned in a comment above.

Comment: Edited original question for additional detail. Tried upvoting, but too low rep ;)